# Unable to find package 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR'

Tags: c#, signalr, nuget, nuget-package

While installing package 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR' I am getting below error for command

`>   PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR`

> The source at All
>   [(Aggregate source)] is unreachable. Falling back to NuGet Local Cache
>   at C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache Install-Package :
>   Unable to find package 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR'. At line:1 char:16
>   + Install-Package <<<<  Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025409/source-unreachable-when-using-the-nuget-package-manager-console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest going to tools/nuget package manager/ manage nuget packages for solutions. That way you can browse the packages and needed dependencies and don't need to worry about typos in the console.

[image]

[image]