# Unable to install NuGet package: Falling back to NuGet Local Cache

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, nuget, google-api-dotnet-client

I am new in the stack overflow community. Right now I am learning c#(using visual studio 2012) and working on uploading files in a google drive.

I followed this tutorial
http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-c-upload/
but sadly I have getting error when executing this command

> Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v2
>
> The source at All [(Aggregate source)] is unreachable. Falling back to
>   NuGet Local Cache at C:\Users\Cyclone\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
>   Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Google.Apis.Drive.v2'. At
>   line:1 char:1
>   + Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v2
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand

I don't really know the problem and can't continue on my project. Could someone explain me how to solve this error or any work around in uploading files in a google drive.

Thank you and sorry for the bad English!

Comment: First answer in Google when searching for **Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v2 ERROR The source at All [(Aggregate source)] is unreachable** is [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025409/source-unreachable-when-using-the-nuget-package-manager-console)

Comment: Thank you for the help
This do the trick
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025409/source-unreachable-when-using-the-nuget-package-manager-console

Comment: BTW Drive v3 is out now but I don't have a tutorial for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe adding  `-Source nuget.org` to your command would fix this?

So try the command:

```
Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v2 -Source nuget.org
```

Or, you can also try `http://www.nuget.org/api/v2` instead of `nuget.org`

If this works, you may have your Package Source misconfigured.

Comment: I am having Invalid URI error

**Install-Package : Invalid URI: The format of the URI could not be determined.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v2 -Source nuget.org
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], UriFormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UriFormatException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand**

Comment: Sometimes microsoft visual studio doesn't like -Source. Try without it if you still get errors. Thanks a lot @Peter

Answer (score 0):

Please try to open user visual studio with admin rights and the project should be using at least .net version 4.0. You can also download sample project from [github](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Google-Drive/Google-Drive-Api-dotnet).

Note: I have tried Nuget install package command and it works. 
[Install-Package Google.Apis.Drive.v2 works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzcnQ.png)