# Not able to use Nuget in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: nuget, nuget-package-restore

I am getting this error:

```
PM> Install-Package GemBox.Document -Version 33.0.1290
The source at nuget.org [https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/] is unreachable. Falling back to NuGet Local Cache at C:\Users\ho7035\AppData\Local\NuGet\Cache
Install-Package : Unable to find version '33.0.1290' of package 'GemBox.Document'.
At line:1 char:1
```

Comment: Ensure the system where you're running this command is connected to internet, and nuget.org is accessible from it.

Also, check out this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025409/source-unreachable-when-using-the-nuget-package-manager-console

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Source unreachable when using the NuGet Package Manager Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24025409/source-unreachable-when-using-the-nuget-package-manager-console)